# Update values without reloading using HTML and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to update the value of the first user with the second user without reloading, using HTML and PHP.

**user.html**

```
 <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <h1>color</h1>
        <body>
          <div id="txtHint">
         <form name="myForm" action="color.php" method="get">
         <tr><td>color<input type='text' name='color' id='clr/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='submit'  id='submit' name='submit' onclick=''/></td></tr>
         </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**color.php**

```
<?php
$color=$_GET['color'];
?>
```

For example, user types "red" and therefore displays "red" in the PHP page:

**user2.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <h1>color</h1>
    <body>
      <div id="txtHint">
     <form name="myForm" action="color.php" method="get">
     <tr><td>color<input type='text' name='color' id='clr'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='submit'  id='submit' name='submit' onclick=''/></td></tr>
     </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want the output such that once user 2 types any color, the color of user 1 also gets changed to the user2 color. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You will need ajax to do this.

Only echo in php page can do nothing. You need to save the color to a database.

In the user.html page you should check periodically for changes in the database. And in the user2.html page you need to update the database using ajax or do a normal post or get method.